# Selecting a value in a select box after the value has been added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

How can I select my newly added value in the select box (dropdown) after the value that was inputted into the textbox and the add button was clicked?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function addref(value) {
        var x = document.getElementById("thebox");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = value
        x.add(option,x.options[null])
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <select id="thebox">
      </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="theinput"/>
    <input type="button" value="Add" name="B1" onclick="addref(document.getElementById('theinput').value)"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`x.selectedIndex = x.options.length - 1;`

After this you can retrieve the value using

```
var val = x.value;
```

or

```
var val = x[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

[`<select>` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement).

Also, instead of `x.add(option,x.options[null])` rather use simply `x.add(option)`. This will add the newly created `option` at the end of the `options`. The second argument is supposed to be an integer, which represents an index position where to add a new option.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value, use this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("thebox");
var theValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

To get the selected text, use this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("thebox");
var theText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

It does not matter if it was added dynamically.